# Ionic4 <ion-page> can't display 100% width and height, how to make one page fit the screen?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

```
<ion-page class="page">
<ion-toolbar>

        <ion-buttons slot="start">
          <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
        </ion-buttons>
</ion-toolbar>
</ion-page>
```

The `<ion-page>` can't display 100% width and height, how to solve this?  Thank you.

I tried the `<ion-page fullscreen>`, it can't work also.

Comment: add screenshot.

Comment: Hi, It seems didn't work.

Comment: you can debug there might be margin and padding in parents elements.

Comment: No, I didn't custom the css, just use the default settings, and the 'fullscreen' works it the tabs page, the elements show width 100%, when create a new sub page, it display like there has a margin :<